# Calligraphy and artist on painting - help translating

Tags: character-identification

I bought this painting from a charity shop because I love the colours and composition. Although I'm Chinese, I can't read calligraphy easily and I can only work out a few words like 寒, 艳 and 天. Please could anyone help me to work out what the writing says and also if possible, who the artist is? Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- 寒(cold)
- 香(fragrant)
- 吐(extrude)
- 艳(beauty)

> 寒香吐艳 (fragrant flower bloom in the cold) - it is the title of the painting

浪天 (Lang Tian) is the artist's name

The red seal also read 浪天

浪天画于香江 (drawn in Hong Kong by Lang Tian)

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for this information. This is really helpful. I didn't realise that 香江 is another term for Hong Kong until I looked it up so I have learned many new things.

Answer (score 0):

right column：寒香吐艳

left column：浪天画于香江

Here are examples of some characters in 草书 (pictures were both taken from 词典网)

画：

[image: 画]

香：

[image: 香]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for the examples of characters in 草书. There seems to be a radical to the left of 良. Could it be 浪 and would that make sense to the whole phrase because there aren't any waves in the painting.

Comment: I've been told by a family friend who wasn't able to work out the characters that 'the painting captures the essence of natural beauty and renewal. The blossoming red plum flowers, known as “红梅” (hóng méi), symbolize perseverance and hope. In Chinese culture, these flowers are often associated with the strength and resilience required to endure the harshness of winter, blooming vibrantly with the arrival of spring. The painting likely conveys a message of enduring grace and the promise of new beginnings.'
What a wonderful symbolism!

Comment: It is 浪天 . See the seal, 浪天 is the artist's name

Comment: @Qinglian yeah maybe it's 浪 rather than 良